# How to inject the same service multiple time in an Angular application and keep track of it in the parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-changedetection

I have a situation where there are multiple selections created by this component (they are sort of radio buttons, but they are not)

Here the **component**:

```js
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleSelectionService } from './simple-selection.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-simple-selection',
    templateUrl: './simple-selection.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./simple-selection.component.scss'],
    providers: [SimpleSelectionService],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SimpleSelectionComponent {
    @Input() public items: Array<any> = [];
    @Input() public selectedItem: any;
    @Input() public key: string = 'value';
    @Input() public disabled: boolean = false;
    @Input() public noWrap: boolean = false;

    constructor(public simpleSelectionService: SimpleSelectionService) { }

    public selectItem(item: any) {
        if (!this.disabled) {
            this.selectedItem = item[this.key];
            this.simpleSelectionService.selectedItemChanged$.next(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And here the **template**:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{ 'is-disabled': disabled }">
    <div class="button-group" [ngClass]="{ 'no-wrap': noWrap }">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
            <span
                class="button button__select-group"
                [innerHtml]="item[key]"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-selected': item[key] === selectedItem }"
                (click)="selectItem(item)"
            ></span>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

The **service** provided in the component is this very simple one:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SimpleSelectionService {
    public get selectedItemChanged$() {
        return this._selectedItemChanged;
    }
    private _selectedItemChanged = new Subject();
}
```

Now the parent component has many instances of `app-simple-selection` and every time one of those selection is clicked, the other selections can change the availability and or the the values passed in as inputs.

**Parent component**:

```html
<app-simple-selection
    id="analytics-capacity"
    [selectedItem]="selectedCapacity"
    [items]="availableCapacities"
    [disabled]="capacitySelectionDisabled"
    [noWrap]="true"
></app-simple-selection>

<app-simple-selection
    id="analytics-colors"
    [selectedItem]="selectedColors"
    [items]="availableColors"
    [noWrap]="true"
></app-simple-selection>

<app-simple-selection
    id="analytics-upfront-cost"
    [selectedItem]="selectedUpfrontCost"
    [items]="availableUpfrontCosts"
    [disabled]="upFrontCostSelectionDisabled"
    [noWrap]="true"
></app-simple-selection>
```

Now in my mind is the parent component that needs to subscribe for each one of those selection to the service, so the service needs to be injected in 3 different instances.

And here the question: how to do that?

And by the way is this the correct way on how to implement something like that?

---

EDIT: added [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbqgpo)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the changes in the parent component just inject the service 1x and subscribe to the [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject) using [`asObservable`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/Subject)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleSelectionService } from './simple-selection.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent-selection',
    providers: [SimpleSelectionService],
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private readonly simpleSelectionService: SimpleSelectionService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.simpleSelectionService.selectedItemChanged$
            .asObservable()
            .subcribe(item => {/* do something */});
    }
}
```

---

Note that because you are already decorating the service with `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` the service is already a [singleton](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#using-providedin) in your application and there will only ever be one instance created by the angular dependency injection framework.

Comment: Ok, but how can I understand if the button clicked is coming from the first or the second or the third `app-simple-selection`? For every one of them, the subscription has to do different actions...

Comment: @Ferie - Pass what you need in `selectedItemChanged$.next(item);`. You could extend the argument as `{ item: any, sender: any}` and then do `selectedItemChanged$.next({item: item, sender: someIdentifier });`

Comment: For some reason I am not able to make it work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tbqgpo @Igor

Comment: @Ferie - What do you mean by not work? I checked your stackblitz, only thing I can see wrong is that the first emit is a `null` value but you can check for that in the subscribe (or you can catch it at the emit). after that i see the sender information along with the item when clicking on a product.

Comment: The subscriber is not working: it is not working in the parent component (Product). I am expecting to see the data from  `console.log('this.data indide Product', this.data);` so when the value changes, I can start another function to do stuff, but it is not working. @Igor

Comment: @Ferie - I am not seeing what you are I guess because your stackblitz works the way I expect it to. See image with the console output, is this not correct? https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjqY6.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199027/discussion-between-ferie-and-igor).

Comment: Please open the Product component, there is another console log.
In there, I am expecting another console log every time there is a change in the value, so another one after the one that you are quoting. @Igor

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a singleton.

> Singleton services
>
> A singleton service is a service for which only one instance exists in an app.
>
> For a sample app using the app-wide singleton service that this page describes, see the live example / download example showcasing all the documented features of NgModules.
> Providing a singleton service
>
> There are two ways to make a service a singleton in Angular:
>
> 1. Declare root for the value of the @Injectable() providedIn property
> 2. Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only imported by the AppModule

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: @Ferie I see now. Your children probably shouldn't be instantiating services at all. A more familiar pattern is to pass state from parent to child, which would solve your problem. Or have all objects share the same instance of your state.